# Start an asynchronous operation in one thread, and cancel it from another one

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

The .Net Framework has classes that were written before the `TPL` library, in which one method starts an async operation (without returning a `Task`), and another one cancel it.

Is it safe to create an object of the class and start the async operation in one thread, and sometime later call the method that cancel the operation from another thread (or from the Thread Pool)?

**A concrete example**: The class `SpeechRecognitionEngine` from `System.Speech.Recognition` has the method `RecognizeAsync` that starts an async speech recognition session. To cancel it you call `RecognizeAsyncCancel`. The method `RecognizeAsyncCancel`, is, by itself, synchronous. It takes about 300ms to return. What If I call it from the thread pool in order to avoid blocking the UI, like this:

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => MySpeechEngine.RecognizeAsyncCancel());
```

Comment: What is `RecognizeAsyncCancel` doing that it takes 300ms? Perhaps share the code.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: Can you explain what do you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure how `RecognizeAsyncCancel` is actually cancelling the `Task`. I was wondering what the said method is actually doing that it causes your UI to freeze.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: The method is from a class from the .Net Framework. It was not written by me. And it does not return a Task.

Comment: Calling cancel from a threadpool thread shouldn't be a problem, unless this cancel has anything to do with your UI controls. But, I'm just curious as to what this actually does. What do you mean by *The method is from a class from the .Net Framework*? Are you talking about the Cancel method? If so,which part of the framework exposes it?

Comment: It is from System.Speech.Recognition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124206/discussion-between-bohoo-and-yuval-itzchakov).